# npm Node output steam to pretty json to terminal

Tags: node.js, json, bash, npm, jq

I want to be able to stream all the output data from when I run `npm run start` into pretty JSON. The issue when using `jq` is that some output is not `JSON` is there any way to pretty-print JSON from an output stream where sometimes its text and sometimes it's JSON

Example id like

```
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts index.js`
helmet deprecated helmet.noCache is deprecated and will be removed in [11:11:55] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[{"caller": "RESOURCE ACCESS","token": "","msg": "xxx","statusCode": null,"level": "info","time": "xxx"},{"endpoint": "some endpoint","msg": "Initial endpoint","data": {"campaign_id": "xxx"},"level": "info","time": "xxx"},{"msg": "Request received","endpoint": "some other endpoint","method": "GET"}]
```

To be formatted in the terminal like

```
[nodemon] 1.19.4
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): src/**/*
[nodemon] watching extensions: ts
[nodemon] starting `ts-node ./src/index.ts index.js`
helmet deprecated helmet.noCache is deprecated and will be removed in [11:11:55] Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.

[
  {
    "caller": "RESOURCE ACCESS",
    "token": "",
    "msg": "xxx",
    "statusCode": null,
    "level": "info",
    "time": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "endpoint": "some endpoint",
    "msg": "Initial endpoint",
    "data": {
      "campaign_id": "xxx"
    },
    "level": "info",
    "time": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "msg": "Request received",
    "endpoint": "some other endpoint",
    "method": "GET"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your sample input is valid JSON, so using `… | jq .` will pretty-print it as desired. Can you provide a sample that contains such a "non-JSON" part?

Comment: @pmf I updated the example. Your solution below worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your output may have JSON parts and non-JSON parts, you first need to find a way to isolate them in order to tell them apart.

For instance, if each item is on its own line (ie. all JSON parts are self-contained within their own line, then read in linewise as raw text using the `--raw-input` (or `-R`) option, check if you can convert them to JSON using the `fromjson` builtin and the error suppression operator `?`, and if not (using the  alternative operator `//`) output the line as is using the `--raw-output` (or `-r` option):

```
… | jq --raw-input --raw-output 'fromjson? // .'
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/zcqMvxTFJ9)